# Java and Javascript - different results using Unsigned right shift operator

Tags: javascript, java

I did a code migration from javascript to java,
but the results for the following operation are different:

in javascript:`-1316818646 >>> 0` = `2978148650`
but in java: `-1316818646 >>> 0` = `-1316818646`

Could someone help me, please? I didn't find the answer elsewhere

Comment: I'm super sorry, I, in no way mean to be mean...but what are you even talking about? Java and Javascript are not the same thing in any instance. Maybe in terms of objects being possible lately but still...there is nothing to go on here either show `java` or show `JS`. I'm confused as to what you are trying

Comment: I need the result of code executed in java to be the same as code executed in javascript (2978148650)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Pydawan said, `2978148650` is just the unsigned value of `-1316818646` or `10110001100000101111000100101010`. To get that in Java, call

```
Integer.toUnsignedLong(-1316818646)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java the operator returns you the same number as an int. In JavaScript the >>> operator always returns you an unsigned 32-bit integer.